# Trying to gain intuition for curve-fitting function in scipy

Tags: python, math, statistics, statsmodels, numerical-methods

I'd like to gain some intuition behind the scipy function scipy.optimize.curve_fit(). Below, I've written a simple version trying to minimise the sum of least squares function(the weights are all 1), with the model being sin(omega*t). I employ the Newton-Raphson method(with central difference approximation) to find the zero of the derivative. The code below should show the fitting (root finding) fail for a few initial value guesses (see the loop), and show successful fits to the (known) parameter value for initial values close enough to the educated guess. The fastest (fewest number of iterations) converged result is then taken to make the plot, showing the artificial data and the best fit curve.

I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: l_sq() missing 1 required positional argument: 'par'
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_func(t, freq):
    ''' model function, unit amplitude.'''
    return np.sin(freq * t)

def Newton_Raphson(func, x0, dx, args, eps=1.e-9, Nmax=20):
    ''' Newton-Raphson root finder function. Default precision and maximum number of iterations.'''
    ff = args[0]
    ts = args[1]
    da = args[2]
    for it in range(Nmax + 1):
        F = func(ff, ts, da)
        if ( abs (F) <= eps ): # Converged?
            print ( " Root found , f(root) = ",F, " , eps = ",eps, ", iterations = ",it)
        df = (func(ff, ts, da, x0+dx/2) + func(ff, ts, da, x0-dx/2))/x0 # Central difference
        dx = -F / df
        x0 += dx # New guess
    if it >= Nmax:
        print ( "Newton Failed for Nmax = " , Nmax)
    return x0, it

def l_sq(model, x, data, par):
    ''' Least-Squares objective function to solve for fitting.'''
    return np.sum((data+model(x,par))*np.gradient(model(x,par),x))


# artificial data first
par   = 4.5 # [Hz] YR: correct
times = np.linspace(0,1,1000) # [s] YR: correct
data  = my_func(times, par) # noise-free data first, at set frequency

# small amount of noise added, just 10% error
data += np.random.normal(scale=0.1,size=len(data)) # YR: correct

# find the root of the first derivative of the least_square function - extremum
step = 1.e-4 # YR: correct
roots = []
nits  = []
for val in range(-7,7): # YR: range as intended, correct
    p0 = par+0.01*val*par # YR: correct, get single figure percent changes only
    root, nit = Newton_Raphson(l_sq, p0, step, args=(my_func, times, data))
    print('root = ', root)
    roots.append(root)
    nits.append(nit)
root = roots[np.argmin(nits)] # YR: lowest n iterations, best fit from initial value series, important for test.

# plot data and best fit curve. YR: correct plotting
plt.plot(times,data,'r.') # red
plt.plot(times, my_func(times, root),'b') # blue
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('sin($\omega$t)')
plt.show()
```

Here is the updated code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_func(t, freq):
    ''' Model function, unit amplitude.'''
    return np.sin(freq * t)

def Newton_Raphson(func, x0, dx, args, eps=1.e-9, Nmax=20):
    ''' Newton-Raphson root finder function. Default precision and maximum number of iterations.'''
    ff = args[0]
    ts = args[1]
    da = args[2]
    for it in range(Nmax + 1):
        F = l_sq(ts, da, x0, my_func)  # Calculate F using l_sq function
        if abs(F) <= eps:  # Converged?
            print("Root found , f(root) = ", F, ", eps = ", eps, ", iterations = ", it)
            break  # Exit the loop when converged
        df = (l_sq(ts, da, x0 + dx / 2, my_func) - l_sq(ts, da, x0 - dx / 2, my_func)) / dx  # Central difference
        dx = -F / df
        x0 += dx  # New guess
    if it >= Nmax:
        print("Newton Failed for Nmax = ", Nmax)
    return x0, it

def l_sq(x, data, par, model):
    ''' Least-Squares objective function to solve for fitting.'''
    return np.sum((data - model(x, par))**2)

# Artificial data first
par = 4.5  # [Hz]
times = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)  # [s]
data = my_func(times, par)  # Noise-free data first, at set frequency

# Add a small amount of noise, just 10% error
data += np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(data))

# Find the root of the first derivative of the least_square function (extremum)
step = 1.e-4
roots = []
nits = []

for val in range(-7, 7):
    p0 = par + 0.01 * val * par
    root, nit = Newton_Raphson(l_sq, p0, step, args=(my_func, times, data))
    print('root = ', root)
    roots.append(root)
    nits.append(nit)

# Find the best fit from the initial value series
root = roots[np.argmin(nits)]

# Plot data and best-fit curve
plt.plot(times, data, 'r.')  # Red dots for data
plt.plot(times, my_func(times, root), 'b')  # Blue curve for best fit
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('sin($\omega$t)')
plt.show()
```

[image: The first output:]

[image: Output after rerunning:]

Comment: what's you "central difference" df supposed to compute? It's not a finite difference approximation to a derivative.

Answer (score 1):

As defined, the `l_sq()` function takes 4 parameters.

```
def l_sq(model, x, data, par)
```

However when it's called there are only 3 values passed.

```
F = func(ff, ts, da)
```

Comment: I see. I've remedied that by passing my_func as an argument to l_sq and perform the operations within l_sq directly with the model function. when I run the code, it gives me a nice blue curve, with the dots fitting it nicely. however, when I run it again, the blue curve has an insane frequency. Sometimes it gives me a nice answer, and sometimes it doesn't. why? I'll add on my new code below

Comment: Update the question with your new code. Don't add it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to SO. I've done that now.